# Apache Spark - Transformation - Row values as column headers - Pivot

Tags: apache-spark, pivot, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset like below
(id, date, price)

```
 - 1, 2017-01-10, 100
 - 1, 2017-01-11, 110
 - 2, 2017-01-10, 100
 - 2, 2017-01-12, 120
```

I need the result in following

```
pidx/date : 2017-01-10  2017-01-11 2017-01-12
1:           100         110         -
2:           100         -          120
```

Which transformations will result in the above output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pivot` with `groupBy` to get the output

```
import spark.implicits._

//dummy data 
val df = Seq(
  (1, "2017-01-10", 100),
  (1, "2017-01-11", 110),
  (2, "2017-01-10", 100),
  (2, "2017-01-12", 120)
).toDF("id", "date", "price")

//first groupBy id and pivot the date and calculate the sum 
val resultDF = df.groupBy("id").pivot("date").agg(sum("price"))

resultDF.show()
```

Output:

```
+---+----------+----------+----------+
|id |2017-01-10|2017-01-11|2017-01-12|
+---+----------+----------+----------+
| 1 |100       |110       |null      |
| 2 |100       |null      |120       |
+---+----------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Oh great. Didn't know the pivot function exists. Thanks!